# How do we communicate between a pc and a beaglebone-black using wifi?

Tags: wifi, beaglebone-black, python

I have been working on a beaglebone-black based mini project which involves displaying a GUI on a screen and displaying sensor values. I have been using python to create the GUI and also interacting sensor slaves connected to the beaglebone.

I have to also send regular packets of sensor data received in the beaglebone-black to a pc. I have thought of connecting the beaglebone to a wlan using a usb dongle and transmitting data over the wlan to the pc. Are there any particular libraries in python or linux to transmit such mini packets to the pc at a fast rate?

The problem is that my pc will have a GUI which will take these values and process them in a more user friendly manner (graphs, lists, etc)

A few references regarding connection of wifi with beaglebone:

[1] https://www.crazypi.com/index.php?route=blog/post&post_id=22

Comment: While you are coming at this from an embedded angle, once you specify wifi what you have left is basically a network *software problem* between a linux box (bb) and a PC running whatever.  Further it is arguably a "code search" - ie, it would be off-topic on stack overflow.  Anyway, first question is if they are always on the same subnet or not necessarily.  Generally you may want to at various IoT type frameworks/solutions at least for ideas, and especially if you realize you may have to support traversing firewalled networks.

Answer (score 2):

Without much more details from you, I understand you want to get information straight from the BBB to your PC, so to "capture" it, process/beautify it, and to display it in your GUI.
Depending on the volume and rates of information between both, plus the reliability you'd need to ensure, you could implement a UDP or TCP interface between both.

That's what we did for a transfer between [a board on which a sensor was attached and a PC](https://github.com/kelu124/rechOpen/tree/master/UDP_Tool) for display - we chose UDP for the ease of work (quick and dirty in Python, so that sounded good).

This solution also has the advantage of you being able to "emulate" the sensor data being sent by the BBB.

Of course, this can easily evolve over time!